# Linq : Group by and sum based on another list

Tags: c#, .net, linq, group-by

I have list with below data (fetched from Json column)

```
public class ProductType
{
    public string FieldName{ get; set; }
    public List<string> items { get; set; }
    
}
List contains 
 Cart item1
      item2
      item3


 wish item4
      item2
      item6
```

I have an another List which contains values related to ProductType

```
 public class ProductCost
    {
        public string item { get; set; }
        public int Amount{ get; set; }

    }
 List contains 
    item1 50
    item2  60
```

I need to find sum of each item based on ProductTypes' FieldName column

Now I want to retrieve something like below

A list contains

```
cart sum(Amount of each items eg:110)
wish sum(amount of each items eg:60)
```

I'm sorry, I'm new to LINQ. Can someone help me or share resources where I can get a hint to achieve this? With a for loop I achieved this .But is there any way to find in one linq execution

Comment: Please post example json

Comment: {
        "fieldName": "cart",
        "items": [item1,item2
        ]
    },

Comment: If a ProductType has a item that isn't in ProductCost list. What to do? Ignore? Throw error?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use following query using `Join`, `GroupBy` and `Sum`:

```
List<ProductType> allProductTypes = new List<ProductType>(); // fill
List<ProductCost> allProductCosts = new List<ProductCost>(); // fill

var costsQuery = from pt in allProductTypes
                 from ptItem in pt.items
                 join pc in allProductCosts on ptItem equals pc.item
                 group (pt, ptItem, pc) by pt.FieldName into fieldGrp
                 select (FieldName: fieldGrp.Key, SumAmount: fieldGrp.Sum(x => x.pc.Amount));

List<ProductCost> totalCosts = costsQuery
    .Select(x => new ProductCost {item = x.FieldName, Amount = x.SumAmount})
    .ToList();
```